# Safari leaves space between element

Tags: html, css

I have problem with my accordion, it leaves white space between on safari, checked on iphone 7. Why is this happening. Is my css wrong? How can I fix this? I have added picture on how it looks properly on Android, and on wrong on Safari.

```
 <button class="faq__tab">Question
                <img src='img/plus.svg'  class="plus">
                <img src='img/minus-svg.png' class="minus">

            </button>
            <div class="faq__panel">
                <p>texttttttttttttttttttttttttt
                </p>
            </div>
```

```
.faq__tab {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px;
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--titles) !important;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Poppins;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.faq__panel {
  max-height: 0px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline elements have **descenders** (pre-defined padding) by default.

What we are doing is changing the inline `<img>` tags by declaring them as block elements and removing the default padding.

EDIT: Since you are using flexbox, simply add this line to the parent container `.faq__tab`

```
flex-direction: column;
```

Since `.faq__tab` is a flex container it already has a display type of block and all elements within it are also block elements.

`flex-direction: column;` places the image elements on top of one another as block elements. This should remove any unnecessary default padding.

An example is below using the code you provided:

```css
.faq__tab {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px;
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--titles) !important;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Poppins;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.faq__panel {
  max-height: 0px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button class="faq__tab">
                <img src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/01/29/16/34/background-616360__340.jpg'  class="plus">
                <img src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/01/29/16/34/background-616360__340.jpg' class="minus">

            </button>
            <div class="faq__panel">
                <p>texttttttttttttttttttttttttt
                </p>
            </div>
```

Comment: It would be useful to also know why `display: block` fixes the problem...

Comment: in the faq__tab can there be to odisplays? because there is display: flex and display: block in the code you provided

Comment: You are correct, I didn't realize you were using flexbox. - I've updated my answer, an image class won't be required.

Comment: Revisiting some of my old answers. @Dave - if this helped solve your problem, can you kindly mark this answer correct by clicking the checkmark? It will help others who have similar issues in the future. - Happy coding!